# Guarantee all actions trigger visible react observer updates

Tags: mobx, mobx-react

I have a series of actions I'd like to run as fast as possible while still guaranteeing react observer components update after every action, i.e. it'd be great if it just ran as close to 60fps as it could, only slowing down if an update was too heavy.

My initial solution was something like:

```
while(todoCount){
  runInAction(()=>...) // state changes in here _must_ be visualized. 
  await sleepFrame(); // returns a promise that resolves using a single frame   requestAnimationFrame based timeout.
  todoCount--;
}
```

But some updates still clump (two sets of state changes in one frame) but also max out at one update per two frames.

Regardless of what's affecting the timing of my specific code it seems like there should be an idiomatic way to guarantee every state change is presented to a user.